# Deserializing map key with Gson expects an object

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, gson

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: 
Expecting object found: "com.shagie.app.SimpleMap$Data@24a37368"
```

when trying to deseralize a Map that uses non-trivial keys:

```
package com.shagie.app;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SimpleMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.m.put(new Data("f", 1), new Data("foo", 3));
        w.m.put(new Data("b", 2), new Data("bar", 4));

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.setPrettyPrinting();
        Gson g = gb.create();

        String json = g.toJson(w);

        System.out.println(json);

        w = g.fromJson(json, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(w.m.isEmpty());
    }

    static public class Wrapper {
        HashMap<Data, Data> m = new HashMap<Data, Data>();
    }

    static public class Data {
        String s;
        Integer i;
        public Data(String arg, Integer val) { s = arg; i = val; }
    }
}
```

This serializes to the json:

```
{
  "m": {
    "com.shagie.app.SimpleMap$Data@24a37368": {
      "s": "foo",
      "i": 3
    },
    "com.shagie.app.SimpleMap$Data@66edc3a2": {
      "s": "bar",
      "i": 4
    }
  }
}
```

One can see the key attempting to be serialized, but certainly not in a way that can be deserialized.

How does one serialize this object so that it can be deserialized?

Comment: While I did find an answer to this that works, I am not convinced that it is the optimal solution or if there's something in the API that I'm missing that would cause GSON to just do what I really want it to.

Answer (score 13):

I found the following while trying to solve this puzzle: [Issue 210:    Cannot serialize or deserialize Maps with complex keys](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=210).

> For any internet travelers from the future (like myself)... you can enable this functionality in GSON 2.* with the enableComplexMapKeySerialization() method on GsonBuilder.

Here's the [javadoc for that method](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization%28%29).

When enabled, the map will be serialized (and correctly deserialized) as an array of [key, value] arrays:

```
{"m":[[{"s":"f", "i",1}, {"s":"foo", "i":3}], [{"s":"b", "i",2}, {"s":"bar", "i":4}]]}
```

Comment: This is "THE" solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `toString()` is getting called on the keys to the map, rather than them being serialized themselves.

To fix this a custom serializer and deserializer needs to be set up, *and* the deserializer needs to be aware of the format that the object uses to display itself as a string (the `toString()` method must return a string that can be used to reconstruct the entire object).

For the above example:

```
package com.shagie.app;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SimpleMapFixed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.m.put(new Data("f", 1), new Data("foo", 3));
        w.m.put(new Data("b", 2), new Data("bar", 4));

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.setPrettyPrinting();
        gb.registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataSerializer());
        Gson g = gb.create();

        String json = g.toJson(w);
        System.out.println(json);

        w = g.fromJson(json, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(w.m.isEmpty());
    }

    static public class Wrapper {
        HashMap<Data, Data> m = new HashMap<Data, Data>();
    }

    static public class DataSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Data>,
                                                  JsonDeserializer<Data> {
        @Override
        public Data deserialize(JsonElement je, Type t, JsonDeserializationContext ctx)
                throws JsonParseException {
            Data rv;
            JsonObject jo;

            System.out.println("deserialize called with: " + je.toString());

            if (je.isJsonObject()) {
                jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
                rv = new Data(jo.get("s").getAsString(), jo.get("i").getAsInt());
            } else {
                String js = je.getAsString();
                String[] s = js.split(":", 2);  // split into two (and only two)
                rv = new Data(s[1], Integer.valueOf(s[0]));
            }

            System.out.println("deserialize returns: " + rv.s + " " + rv.i);
            return rv;
        }

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Data data, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
            JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
            jo.addProperty("s", data.s);
            jo.addProperty("i", data.i);
            System.out.println("serialize called: " + jo.toString());
            return jo;
        }
    }

    static public class Data {
        String s;
        Integer i;

        public Data(String arg, Integer val) { s = arg; i = val; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String rv = i.toString() + ':' + s;
            System.out.println("toString called: " + rv);
            return rv;
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code produces:

```
serialize called: {"s":"foo","i":3}
toString called: 1:f
serialize called: {"s":"bar","i":4}
toString called: 2:b
{
  "m": {
    "1:f": {
      "s": "foo",
      "i": 3
    },
    "2:b": {
      "s": "bar",
      "i": 4
    }
  }
}
deserialize called with: "1:f"
deserialize returns: f 1
deserialize called with: {"s":"foo","i":3}
deserialize returns: foo 3
deserialize called with: "2:b"
deserialize returns: b 2
deserialize called with: {"s":"bar","i":4}
deserialize returns: bar 4
```

Note the invocations of `toString()` as part of the serialization.  In this code, the logic for the deserializion from the String form is in the `DataSerializer`, though it may make sense to move it into the `Data` class as another constructor instead - it doesn't affect the final outcome.

Further note that `Data` was a rather simple object itself with no deeper structures.  Trying to serialize that as the key would require additional work.

Comment: This is a good answer, but buried deep in the [Gson Documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) it says: "New applications should prefer `TypeAdapter`, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API."

Answer (score 0):

Its Up to you how you are maintaining the HahMap Keys, You can deserialized it with simple and easiest way.

```
final Type typeOf = new TypeToken <Map<String, Map<String, Data>>>(){}.getType();
final  Map<String, Map<String, Data>> newMap = gson.fromJson(json, typeOf);
final Map<String, Data> map = newMap.get("m");
final Iterator<Entry<String, Data>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry<String,Data> pair = (Map.Entry<String,Data>) it.next();
   String key = pair.getKey();
   System.out.println("key  "+ key + " Values[  i= " + data.getI() + ", s= " +data.getS()+" ]");
       }
```

**Result:**

key = snippet.Snippet$Data@61506150  Values [  i= 3, s= foo ]

key  = snippet.Snippet$Data@63ff63ff Values [  i= 4, s= bar ]