# Serialize HashMap with object keys with Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, hashmap, gson

I am writing some code to serialize a neural network system I have developed. This system has a "database" that keeps track of the evolution of the neural networks, and it does so by storing the ID of each gene in a HashMap with a GeneKey, which is a record containing the ID of the gene before and the ID of the gene after the gene we're storing.

A HashMap with some data looks like this:

```java
existingNodes = {
    GeneKey[a=0, b=3] = 4,
    GeneKey[a=1, b=4] = 5
}
```

Everything in the system serializes fine, except this HashMap, because Json can only have numbers and strings as its keys, and in my HashMap I'm using objects for the keys. Is there an easy way to serialize this to json using Gson?

Edit: This is how the HashMap is constructed:

```java
HashMap<GeneKey, Integer> existingNodes = new HashMap<>();

existingNodes.put(new GeneKey(0, 3), 4);
existingNodes.put(new GeneKey(1, 4), 5);

System.out.println("existingNodes = "+registry); 
//existingNodes = {
//    GeneKey[a=0, b=3] = 4,
//    GeneKey[a=1, b=4] = 5
//}
```

This is the GeneKey class:

```java
public record GeneKey(int a, int b) {}
```

Comment: What is that hashmap? It is not a valid Java code.

Comment: It's what would show up if you printed it to the console. I'll add the way I store data to the question

Comment: Why are you trying to find an _easy_ way for a thing that is not supported by JSON? You have two ways to work around: 1) convert the input map to `Map<String, Integer>` where latter's keys are fully controlled by you (no matter how you encode/decode `GeneKey`), but this will generate as small JSON as possible; 2) make use of `enableComplexMapKeySerialization` that can work around it itself, but I don't think you'll be very happy with the way it generates the JSON (`[[{"a":0,"b":3},4],[{"a":1,"b":4},5]]` for your case).

Comment: Third option: Override `toString()` in `GeneKey` to return your desired format. @user12232870, why not post your comment as answer because that seems to be the proper solution?

Comment: @Marcono1234 Pretty much because my suggestion is just an option, as well as yours is, and it's too trivial for an extended answer (I omitted a note on proper use of generics, though). Also if the core of the problem were properly defined and then googled for say `gson maps custom objects and keys site:stackoverflow.com`, it would save both OP's and our time, because this one is another duplicate for e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209240/ . I guess it sounds pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could give the JSON string which you got after serializing using Gson.

However, please check the following code if this solves your issue.

Define GenKey class with overriden hashCode and equals methods as:

```
public class GeneKey {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    
    public GeneKey(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + a;
        result = prime * result + b;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GeneKey other = (GeneKey) obj;
        if (a != other.a)
            return false;
        if (b != other.b)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return "GeneKey [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
        // Updated for deserialization using Gson
        Gson gson = new 
        GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Now try to convert the HashMap with GenKey as key into JSON String using Gson :

```
HashMap<GeneKey, Integer> existingNodes = new HashMap<>();

existingNodes.put(new GeneKey(0, 3), 4);
existingNodes.put(new GeneKey(1, 4), 5);
        
Gson gson = new 
GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        
System.out.println(gson.toJson(existingNodes));
```

This is the output which I received in my console:

```
 {"{\"a\":0,\"b\":3}":4,"{\"a\":1,\"b\":4}":5}
```

**Updating the answer to add deserialization logic if required:**

```
//Say, we pass the serialized JSON as a payload to some REST API. We can deserialize the Key of the response as follows - 

@PostMapping("/getJson")
public Map<GeneKey, Integer> getJson(@RequestBody Map<String, Integer> response) {
        
  final Gson gson = new Gson();
  Map<GeneKey, Integer> deserializedMap = new HashMap<GeneKey, 
        Integer>();
        
  response.keySet().forEach( k -> {
  GeneKey key = gson.fromJson(k, GeneKey.class);
  deserializedMap.put(key, response.get(k));
        });

  System.out.println(deserializedMap);
  return deserializedMap;
}
```

Comment: This is because you are overridden toString() method. hashCode and equals methods do not make sense there.

Comment: @Eugene Hi, I agree. overriding hashCode() and equals() didn't solve the issue here, but these are necessary when we use a user defined Java object as a key to a Map. Also, I am not sure what is the purpose of serialization here. I assume it is only for representational purpose. If not, and later, the JSON String needs to be deserialized too, then we need to implement a deserialization logic as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 GsonBuilder#enableComplexMapKeySerialization
```

However, now the map is represented by an array of array of entries.

see [Gson Serializing HashMap<Teacher, List<Student>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675374/gson-serializing-hashmapteacher-liststudent)